# Adding every entry of two tables

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation, summation

I have to randomly create a polymer (random angle between parts), change a random angle by a bit (delta), and determine the energy difference. RandomAngle contains all the angles and DeltaTable contains a random delta value for a specific angle. I want to add this delta value to the original angles (AdjusteRandomAngle), but somehow this doest work. The output doesn't add up as it should. Could someone help?

````
Module[{},
  \[Delta] = Random[Real, {-0.01, 0.01}];
  RandomAngle := 
   Table[{b, Random[Real, {-\[Pi], \[Pi]}]}, {i, 1, Ntot - 1}];
  CoordinatesRandom := AnglePath[RandomAngle];
  E1 := (\[Kappa]/(2 b)) Total[(RandomAngle)^2][[2]];
  RandomAngleNumber := Random[Integer, {1, Ntot - 1}];
  ZeroTable := Table[{0, 0}, {i, 1, Ntot - 1}];
  DeltaTable := 
   ReplacePart[ZeroTable, {0, \[Delta]}, RandomAngleNumber];
  AdjustedRandomAngle = DeltaTable + RandomAngle ;
  
  
  Print[ListLinePlot[CoordinatesRandom]];
  Print[E1];
  Print[RandomAngleNumber];
  Print[\[Delta]];
  Print[RandomAngle];
  Print[DeltaTable];
  Print[AdjustedRandomAngle];
  ]; 
```
````

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Can you please put together a minimal working example with inputs and a sample output? The code you have posted does not evaluate currently.

Comment: Perhaps this example will assist you further in reformulating your question. `alist = {a1, a2, a3, a4};
blist = {b1, b2, b3, b4};
MapThread[Plus, {alist, blist}]`.

Comment: One problem with your code is too many :=. When you say x:=Random[ ] it will give new random numbers every time you mention x. Thus in your case, RandomAngle in CoordinatesRandomAngle is a different set of random numbers than RandomAngle in E1.

Answer (score 1):

As a first step, you may use a demonstration that I used for a lecture. You will need to adapt it for your purposes. The demonstrator makes the steps of the unit length along the x, y, or z-axis in the 3D space. Type in a number of steps into the input field at the top of the outer panel and press "Enter". Then click on the black triangle on the upper part of the internal panel. The interactive demonstration will start drawing the Gaussian coil. The end-to-end vector is shown by the red arrow. Rotating the coil one can visualize its 3D structure.

```
[![Manipulate\[
 list = Accumulate\[RandomInteger\[{-1, 1}, {stepsNumber, 3}\]\];
 xmin = Min\[(Transpose@list)\[\[1\]\]\];
 xmax = Max\[(Transpose@list)\[\[1\]\]\];
 ymin = Min\[(Transpose@list)\[\[2\]\]\];
 ymax = Max\[(Transpose@list)\[\[2\]\]\];
 zmin = Min\[(Transpose@list)\[\[3\]\]\];
 zmax = Max\[(Transpose@list)\[\[3\]\]\];
 
 Animate\[
  
  Show\[{
    Graphics3D\[{Blue, Line\[Take\[list, i\]\]}\],
    Graphics3D\[{Darker@Red, Arrowheads\[0.03\], Thickness\[0.005\], 
      Arrow\[{First\[list\], list\[\[i\]\]}\]}\]
    }, PlotRange -> {{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}, {zmin, zmax}}, 
   ImageSize -> {400, 400}\],
  {i, 2, stepsNumber, 1}, AnimationRepetitions -> 1, 
  AnimationRunning -> False\],
 
 {{stepsNumber, 2}, ControlType -> InputField, FieldSize -> 7}, 
 SaveDefinitions -> False\]]
```

[image]

Have fun!